# Calculating values in a hierarchy of a known depth

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to query a few derived values from 2 tables. Their simplified structure is as follows:

#### Users

Users have a ID and a parent column which denotes the ID of their parent. Each user also has a commission value which denotes what % of sales that they get from the employees in their line.

Only employees can make sales and that information is recorded in the next table

```
+------------------------------------+
| ID Name          Parent Commission |
+------------------------------------+
| 1  SeniorManager NULL   5          |
| 2  Manager       1      10         |
| 3  Employee1     2      13         |
| 4  Employee2     2      12         |
+------------------------------------+
```

#### Sales

This table records the sales from the employees linked through their ID. It records the sale amount as well as when the sale was made.

```
+---------------------------+
| user_id amount created_at |
+---------------------------+
| 3       100    2014-01-16 |
| 3       120    2014-01-16 |
| 3       110    2014-01-16 |
+---------------------------+
```

---

From the other parts of the system, I know the depth of a user given his ID. In the actual system, there is 7 fixed levels but I am simplifying it here for the sake of the question.

The query that I am trying to write is that: Given the ID of a SeniorManager and a date range, show a list of managers under him, the aggregated commissions of those managers as well as the commission expected from that manager. So given the data above one would expect:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
| Name    Sales ManagerCommission Commission |
+--------------------------------------------+
| Manager 330   33.30             16.65      |
+--------------------------------------------+
```

The query I have so far is:

```
SELECT
    users.name AS Name,
    SUM(sales.amount) AS Sales,
    SUM(sales.amount) * (users.commission/100) AS ManagerCommission
FROM
    users
LEFT JOIN users AS employees
    ON employees.parent = users.id
LEFT JOIN sales
    ON sales.id = employees.id AND
    sales.created_at BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?)
WHERE
    users.parent = ?
GROUP BY
    users.name
```

I am unsure how to get that last column value of the commission grouped by managers instead of employees. Also as a side question, is there a way to reuse the `SUM(sales.amount)` which is used twice in the select statement. I would rather not calculate the exact same value twice. I am planning on writing 7 queries, for each of the known depths. Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The model you have adopted for storing your hierarchical data is known as an "adjacency list". Sadly, MySQL does not support recursive functions, so using such a model one would have to make a self-join for each level of the hierarchy that one wishes to traverse--but it ought to be readily apparent that that isn't a very scalable solution.  The better advice is to remodel your data using either nested sets or a table of the transitive closure of your graph.

Comment: For a very limited set of data your query should be fine, but I think you need to be checking users.ID in the WHERE clause rather than users.parent.

Comment: @eggyal Assuming that I can't change the way the data is modelled(I'm not the only dev on this project), does it make more sense to do this with the application code rather than go for a SQL solution?

Comment: @Kickstart, A senior manager can have multiple managers under him, so in this case, I will put the ID of the senior manager in question and query against the parent so that I get all the children managers  instead of just one senior manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding one join for each level of management:-

```
SELECT
    senior_manager.name AS Name,
    SUM(sales.amount) AS Sales,
    SUM(sales.amount * manager.commission/100) AS ManagerCommission,
    SUM(sales.amount) * (senior_manager.commission/100) AS SeniorManagerCommission
FROM
    users AS senior_manager
LEFT JOIN users AS manager
    ON manager.parent = senior_manager.id
LEFT JOIN users AS employees
    ON employees.parent = manager.id
LEFT JOIN sales
    ON sales.id = employees.id AND
    sales.created_at BETWEEN DATE(?) AND DATE(?)
WHERE
    senior_manager.id = ?
GROUP BY
    senior_manager.name
```

SQL fiddle for it:-

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cfffe/4